# String to charArray in JavaEditor

Tags: java, arrays, string, vigenere

I have a school project where we need to programm Vigenère coding in JavaEditor so far i only worked on getting the key to be looped, 
so i came up with this:

```
String Message = jTextArea1.getText();
String key = jTextArea3.getText();

char[] key1 = key.toCharArray() ;      
for (int i=0;i<key.length() ;i++ ) {  
key1[i] = key.charAt(i);}

for (int j = 0; j<Message.length(); j++) {
int k = j;
while ( k > key.length()) {
k = k-key.length()-1;}    
infkey.append(key1[k]);}

String finalkey = infkey.toString();
jTextArea2.setText(finalkey);
```

but it wont show anything in jTextArea2, i tested everything and it seems to be the way i convert the String into a char that doesnt work properly :/
All the other Questions on this topic had an explanation with something called 
"ArrayUtils.toObject(str.toCharArray())" but java cant find ArrayUtils.

Comment: `ArrayUtils` is provided by a library, a quick google search got me to the [Commons Lang javadoc](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html#toObject(char[])). But to convert an String to a char[], thats exactly what `String#toCharArray()` does, no need for an extra library or a loop for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can split a String into characters and put it in a vector like this:

```
String myString = "myString";
String[] chars = myString.split("");
//you can work directly with strings,no need for chars
```